# Using For Loop for One Process and Calling that Loop for Same Process in For Loop Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, com

I'm using a COM-interface to get Parameter Names and Values from 3rd part application.

I'm using this VBA script to get Model's standalone parameter file names, and values, Parameter Group names and Paramater Informations and Parameter Group informations in this Group doing same process wherever its ends.

Also there's submodels attached to main model and i'm doing same process for them.

I'm using different variables for each level for loop, but the process is same for every level, so i want to learn isn't there easy way to get it? Without using variables for 2nd level and 3rd level Parameter Groups and Submodels.

Topology of My Functions
[image: Model Scheme]

If you look the topology of the structure you can understand what i mean. I'm using same functions for same process but i have difficulties for the sub-level Parameter Groups i'm using an extra variables for them like;

```
    Dim j1 As Integer               ' Parameter Group of Parameter Group Item / Count
    Dim j2 As Integer               ' Parameter Group of Parameter Group of Parameter Group Item / Count

   Dim ParameterGroupsX1 As Object      '2nd Level Parameter Groups Objects
    Dim ParameterGroupX1 As Object       '2nd Level Parameter Group
    Dim nParameterGroupX1 As Integer     'Number of 2nd Level Parameter Group Objects

    Dim ParameterGroupsX2 As Object      '3rd Level Parameter Groups Objects
    Dim ParameterGroupX2 As Object       '3rd Level Parameter Group
    Dim nParameterGroupX2 As Integer     'Number of 3rd Level Parameter Group Objects
```

and Also i'm using same approach for Submodels

```
Dim s1 As Integer               ' Sub Model 1st Level
Dim s2 As Integer               ' Sub Model 2nd Level

Dim SubstrsX1 As Object           ' 2nd Level Substructures Object
Dim SubstrX1 As Object            ' 2nd Level Substructure
Dim nSubstrX1 As Integer          ' Number of 2nd Level Substructure Objects

Dim SubstrsX2 As Object         ' 3rd Level Substructures Object
Dim SubstrX2 As Object          ' 3rd Level Substructure
Dim nSubstrX2 As Integer        ' Number of 3rd Level Substructure Objects
```

I think i can Call Functions or For Loop without using above variables to define sub-level Parameter Groups and Parameters.

Could you please show me how can i doing same process for my topology.

The code is listed below;

```
Dim Target_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Main_Sheet As Worksheet

Dim ParameterGroups As Object        ' 1st Level Parameter Groups Object
Dim ParameterGroup As Object         ' Single Parameter Group
Dim nParameterGroup As Integer       ' Number of Parameter Group Objects

Dim Parameters As Object             ' 1st Level Parameters Object
Dim Parameter As Object              ' 1st Level Parameter
Dim nParameter As Integer            ' Number of Parameters Objects

Dim ParameterGroupsX1 As Object      '2nd Level Parameter Groups Objects
Dim ParameterGroupX1 As Object       '2nd Level Parameter Group
Dim nParameterGroupX1 As Integer     'Number of 2nd Level Parameter Group Objects

Dim ParameterGroupsX2 As Object      '3rd Level Parameter Groups Objects
Dim ParameterGroupX2 As Object       '3rd Level Parameter Group
Dim nParameterGroupX2 As Integer     'Number of 3rd Level Parameter Group Objects

Dim Substrs As Object             ' 1st Level Substructures Object
Dim Substr As Object              ' 1st Level Substructure
Dim nSubstr As Integer            ' Number of 1st Level Substructure Objects

Dim SubstrsX1 As Object           ' 2nd Level Substructures Object
Dim SubstrX1 As Object            ' 2nd Level Substructure
Dim nSubstrX1 As Integer          ' Number of 2nd Level Substructure Objects

Dim SubstrsX2 As Object         ' 3rd Level Substructures Object
Dim SubstrX2 As Object          ' 3rd Level Substructure
Dim nSubstrX2 As Integer        ' Number of 3rd Level Substructure Objects

Dim i As Integer                ' Parameter Item/Count
Dim j As Integer                ' Parameter Group Item / Count
Dim j1 As Integer               ' Parameter Group of Parameter Group Item / Count
Dim j2 As Integer               ' Parameter Group of Parameter Group of Parameter Group Item / Count
Dim s As Integer                ' Sub Model Main Level
Dim s1 As Integer               ' Sub Model 1st Level
Dim s2 As Integer               ' Sub Model 2nd Level
Dim cLine As Long

Option Explicit


Sub ReadParameterSimpack()          ' Main function get parameter information
Set Target_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Parameters")  ' Parameter's page which i list the names and their values
Call Setup_Module.SetupSimpack          ' This is the module where i get the model information from third part Application
cLine = 0

Set Parameters = Mdl.getParameterList(False)  ' Gettting Parameters List
Call ParameterRead(Parameters, cLine)           ' Calls the Parameter Read Function

Set ParameterGroups = Mdl.getParameterGroupList(False)  ' Getting the Parameter Group List
Call ParameterGroupRead(ParameterGroups, cLine)         ' Calls the Parameter Group Read Function

Set Substrs = Mdl.getSubstrList(False) ' Getting the Sub-Model List
Call SubstructureRead(Substrs, cLine) ' Calls the Model's submodel list

End Sub


Sub ParameterRead(Parameters, cLine)  ' This is the function of reading Parameters

nParameter = Parameters.Count         ' Number of Parameters

For i = 0 To nParameter - 1
Set Parameter = Parameters.Item(i)    ' Getting parameter from the List of Parameter
Target_Sheet.Cells(cLine + 1, 1).Value = Parameter.FullName  ' Writes parameter name to Excel Sheet
cLine = cLine + 1
Next i

End Sub


Sub ParameterGroupRead(ParameterGroups, cLine) ' This is the function of reading Parameter Groups
nParameterGroup = ParameterGroups.Count     ' This is the number of Parameter Groups
For j = 0 To nParameterGroup - 1
Set ParameterGroup = ParameterGroups.Item(j)  'Getting Parameter Group from Parameter Groups List
Target_Sheet.Cells(cLine + 1, 1).Value = ParameterGroup.FullName  ' Writes parameter group name to Excel Sheet
cLine = cLine + 1
Set Parameters = ParameterGroup.getParameterList(False)  'This is getting Parameters listed below the Parameter Group
Call ParameterRead(Parameters, cLine)           ' Calls the parameter read function to get parameters which listed under Parameter groups
cLine = cLine + 1
Set ParameterGroupsX1 = ParameterGroup.getParameterGroupList(False) ' Sub-Level Parameter Group
nParameterGroupX1 = ParameterGroupsX1.Count     ' Number of Sub-Level Parameter Group

For j1 = 0 To nParameterGroupX1 - 1
Set ParameterGroupX1 = ParameterGroupsX1.Item(j1)
Target_Sheet.Cells(cLine + 1, 1).Value = ParameterGroupX1.FullName

Set Parameters = ParameterGroupX1.getParameterList(False)   ' Getting the Parameters of Parameter Groups
Call ParameterRead(Parameters, cLine)                       ' Call Parameter Read Function
cLine = cLine + 1

Set ParameterGroupsX2 = ParameterGroupX1.getParameterGroupList(False) 'Sub SubLevel of Parameter Group
nParameterGroupX2 = ParameterGroupsX2.Count
For j2 = 0 To nParameterGroupX2 - 1
Set ParameterGroupX2 = ParameterGroupsX2.Item(j2)
Target_Sheet.Cells(cLine + 1, 1).Value = ParameterGroupX2.FullName
cLine = cLine + 1
Set Parameters = ParameterGroupX2.getParameterList(False)
Call ParameterRead(Parameters, cLine)
cLine = cLine + 1
Next j2
Next j1
Next j

End Sub

Sub SubstructureRead(Substrs, cLine)
nSubstr = Substrs.Count
For s = 0 To nSubstr - 1
Set Substr = Substrs.Item(s)
Target_Sheet.Cells(cLine + 1, 1).Value = Substr.FullName
cLine = cLine + 1
Set Parameters = Substr.getParameterList(False)
Call ParameterRead(Parameters, cLine)
Set ParameterGroups = Substr.getParameterGroupList(False)
Call ParameterGroupRead(ParameterGroups, cLine)

Set SubstrsX1 = Substr.getSubstrList(False)
nSubstrX1 = SubstrsX1.Count

For s1 = 0 To nSubstrX1 - 1
Set SubstrX1 = SubstrsX1.Item(s1)
Target_Sheet.Cells(cLine + 1, 1).Value = SubstrX1.FullName
cLine = cLine + 1
Set Parameters = SubstrX1.getParameterList(False)
Call ParameterRead(Parameters, cLine)
Set ParameterGroups = SubstrX1.getParameterGroupList(False)
Call ParameterGroupRead(ParameterGroups, cLine)

Set SubstrsX2 = Substr.getSubstrList(False)
nSubstrX2 = SubstrsX2.Count

For s2 = 0 To nSubstrX2 - 1
Set SubstrX2 = SubstrsX2.Item(s2)
Target_Sheet.Cells(cLine + 1, 1).Value = SubstrX2.FullName
cLine = cLine + 1
Set Parameters = SubstrX2.getParameterList(False)
Call ParameterRead(Parameters, cLine)
Set ParameterGroups = SubstrX2.getParameterGroupList(False)
Call ParameterGroupRead(ParameterGroups, cLine)

Next s2
Next s1
Next s
```

End Sub

Comment: Please indent your code, and provide a small sample data of before and after processing. Also you're not providing the full context - there is an `End Sub` missing at the end of your main code, and Setup_Module.SetupSimpack (Mdl) is unknown - we need to [run the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to be able to provide improvements

Comment: @paulbica You're right Mr. Bica, There's my fault i forgot copy the last line. You need a Simpack - MBS Program to run full code. So i didnt insert the main section. My main problem is if you look the Topology image, i have 3 functions. One is listing the parameters the other is listing parameter groups and calling parameter function to list parameters listed under this parameter group. And also Parameter group has some parameter groups (cascaded) and also the last group has groups and parameters its continuening whereever it ends. I'm exporting this parameter names to Excel sheet.

Comment: @paulbica and third function (submodel function) is not so important if we can do it for parameter groups and parameters i can apply same approach for the third one.

Comment: I'm not sure how everything fits together but it looks like you could create your own class(es), and generate / reuse objects as needed, maybe using arrays or dictionaries

Comment: Without reading all your code in detail, it sounds like you need to write Recursive Sub/Function. Recursive allows you to do the same procedures for any number of levels (as much as memory can be allocated). Basically you need a *generic* sub that is recursive, and another sub to *start* it. Treat it like listing all files and sub-folders given a root folder location.

Comment: @PatricK You're absolutely right, I'm looking for exactly this. I search recursive functions on internet, i'm still try to understand usage of it. Do you have any recommends how should be code structure? If you do for your example (fill-folder-subfolder) how would you use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowledge of the Class/Object you have, only example can be given. I think in your case you will need 2 recursive Subs. Top 1 for Model, then recurse the ParameterGroup.

```
Option Explicit

Private oFSO As Object

Sub ListFilesFromRootFolder()
    ' FileSystemObject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' e.g. List all files and subfolders from User's Temp folder
    ListFilesAndFolders oFSO.GetFolder(Environ("TMP"))
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ListFilesAndFolders(oFDR As Object)
    Dim oFile As Object, oSubFDR As Object
    ' Prints current Folder path
    Debug.Print oFDR.Path
    ' List the files in this folder
    For Each oFile In oFDR.Files
        Debug.Print oFile.Name
    Next
    ' Recurse SubFolders
    For Each oSubFDR In oFDR.SubFolders
        ListFilesAndFolders oSubFDR
    Next
End Sub
```